# How to develop application for OpenStack

Tags: 12.04, php, openstack

I have installed OpenStack and everywhere I see tutorials about installing and deploying but no example about `how to develop a simple app on OpenStack?` using PHP

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use an SDK (Software Development Kit), from https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/SDKs#PHP:

> - [php-opencloud](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud) is a software development kit (SDK) to help developers using PHP to work with OpenStack and other open clouds.
> - [ZendService_OpenStack](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_OpenStack) is a PHP library that implements the last versions of the OpenStack API. It's 100% compliant with the
>     specification of OpenStack.

Comment: Okay thanks! I could not find php-opencloud SDK installation guide... can you tell me? Thanks

Comment: They are on the linked page (below the list of source files), afraid I can't help you with any details of how to install though.